# Function to check a null string property?

Tags: c#, properties, null-coalescing

I have an object with `string` properties, for example, a Patient object with weight and height.

But when the property is null, my code fails when I try to use it, as the property is set to null. I'm trying to create a function that checks if the string/property is null, and if so, set the property to `""`.

I know that I can do this:

```
if(string.isNullOrEmpty(patient.weight)) patient.weight = "";
```

But I need the code to be as clean as possible, and I have a lot of properties, so I don't want to manually check each one. Ideally, I'd like to have a function that can take the string, (without failing even if it is null), and simply return either the value if it's not null, or a `""` if it is null.

Can anyone give me a clue on this?

Comment: Could you not just initialize the strings to "" when the object is created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I would ensure those properties can *never* be null by writing them like this:

```
private string _Name = string.Empty;
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _Name;
    }
    set
    {
        _Name = value ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

However, what you're looking for is probably the `??` operator, also known as the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), as used above, basically, this expression:

```
x = y ?? z;
```

means the same as this:

```
if (y != null)
    x = y;
else
    x = z;
```

and that's not entirely true either. In the above example `y` is evaluated twice, which does not happen with the `??` operator so a better approximation would be this:

```
var temp = y;
if (temp != null)
    x = temp;
else
    x = z;
```

Comment: Hum, does anyone see (edit my question and check the source) why my code ends up being formatted as it is? ie. the property is combined on one line like that.

Comment: Fixed it by not inserting EOL before braces `{` and `}`.

Comment: While that might not combine it on one line, that's hardly a fix. Is there a bug in markdown handling of code today?

Comment: Normally when that happens to me I just re-select everything and put another wrap it with the Code formatting again and it fixes it. I did that before Leito's edit but then my internet kicked out for a couple seconds :(. Work connection...

Comment: No, Stack Overflow disappeared for a few seconds, happened to me too.

Comment: Alright haha, glad it wasn't just me. Next time it happens though just highlight the code and try reformatting. Should fix it. It's weird but it works.

Comment: Your last piece of code is blatantly incorrect. The else statement should say `x = z`, not `y = z`.

Comment: @crclayton Agreed, corrected, thanks!, although "blatantly" is probably stretching it. It's not like I went out of my way to write incorrect code :)

Answer (score 2):

Well the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) sounds like it's your friend here:

```
string text = patient.Name ?? "";
```

You *could* write an extension method to do the same thing, but I think the operator's likely to end up being more readable.

Note that this won't *set* the property - but that's not what you say you want anyway, in the sentence:

> Ideally, I'd like to have a function that can take the string, (not fail even if it is null), and simply return either the value (if it's not null), or a "" if it is null.

That's exactly what the code above does.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```
public string EmptyIfNull(string value) 
{
    return value ?? String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the null-coalescing operator:

```
string s = Patient.Name ?? string.Empty;
```

So if `Patient.Name` is null, then `s` will be set to the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `myString ?? string.Empty`, which gives you the string, or string.Empty if it is null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`??` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to return a default value of your choice when any object is null.

```
string a = null;
a = a ?? "womble";
// a now has the value "womble"

string b = "fluff";
b = b ?? "cabbage";
// b wasn't null, so it still has the value "fluff"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking is the best solution for you. If every time you wan't to check a `String` and return `""` if it is `null`, I'd suggest instead that you initialize your `String` fields to `""`.

```
private String height = "";
```

instead of

```
private String height;
```

By the way, you should store values like `height` and `weight` as `Double` and not `String`, unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Say hello to the [null coalescing operator](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2011/09/default-values-for-nulls.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If **Weight** and **Height** are integers they cannot be null.  If your object is **null** and you are trying to get the **Height** of **Weight** of a null object then you code is simply wrong.  If a string is null then it will print a null character.

The following is very elegant:

```
if ( String.isNullOrEmpty(patient.weight) )
{
//DO STUFF HERE
}
else
{
//DO OTHER STUFF HERE
}
```

Please understand if **patient** is null you shouldn't even be in this block of code.

If you are using **isNullOrEmpty** then doing the following is pointless.

```
patient.weight = "";
```

Author's Note

I guess i do not understand the reason a string being null is going to cause a problem.  The points about setting the value to an empty string when intialized are of course valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the idea from @Jon one step further so you don't have to worry about using ?? everywhere:

Define your access methods like this:

```
private String m_name = null;
public String Name
{
    get { return m_name ?? String.Empty; }
    set { m_name = value; }
}
```

Anywhere you access the Name property it will perform the  null coalescing operator for you.